# Form KeyDown event method for Delete key occuring on clearing textbox content using Delete key

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a win form in which form KeyPreview is set 'true' and i wrote code to delete details from database on pressing Delete key in form keydown event. But when i try to clear content in a textbox in the form using Delete key the form keydown event is occuring. How can i prevent form keydown event from occuring on i press Delete to clear a textbox content?

The code i used for Form KeyDown is as

```
Public Sub frm_Customers_KeyDown(ByVal myForm As frm_Customers, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs, ByVal txtTIN As TextBox, ByVal txtCustomerPhone As TextBox, ByVal txtCustomerMobileno As TextBox, ByVal txtCustomerEmail As TextBox, ByVal txtCustomerAddress As TextBox, ByVal btnCustomerSave As Button, ByVal txtCustomerName As TextBox, ByVal txtCustomerAliasname As TextBox, ByVal txtacgroup As TextBox, ByVal txtcustomerOPAmount As TextBox, ByVal UC_autoCompleteComboBox1 As UC_autoCompleteComboBox, ByVal frm As Form, ByVal errorProvider1 As System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider, ByVal rbCredit As RadioButton)

 If e.KeyCode = Keys.F2 Then

   If btnCustomerSave.Tag = 1 Then
        updateprocess(txtTIN, txtCustomerPhone, txtCustomerMobileno, txtCustomerEmail, txtCustomerAddress, btnCustomerSave, txtCustomerName, txtCustomerAliasname, txtacgroup, txtcustomerOPAmount, UC_autoCompleteComboBox1, errorProvider1, rbCredit)
   Else
        saveprocess(txtTIN, txtCustomerPhone, txtCustomerMobileno, txtCustomerEmail, txtCustomerAddress, btnCustomerSave, txtCustomerName, txtCustomerAliasname, txtacgroup, txtcustomerOPAmount, UC_autoCompleteComboBox1, errorProvider1, rbCredit)
   End If

 ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
   deletionprocess(txtTIN, txtCustomerPhone, txtCustomerMobileno, txtCustomerEmail, txtCustomerAddress, btnCustomerSave, txtCustomerName, txtCustomerAliasname, txtacgroup, txtcustomerOPAmount, UC_autoCompleteComboBox1, errorProvider1)
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That means that using Keys.Delete was a very poor choice.  Pick a key, any key, just not one that the user is likely to use when using the window normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to check if the text control has focus. If it does, then go ahead and ignore the keydown press.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried checking `myForm.ActiveControl.Name` with all `textbox.name` control property whether the control present cursor or not and its worked for me. Here is the code i used

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then

   If txtTIN.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Or txtCustomerPhone.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Or txtCustomerMobileno.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Or txtCustomerEmail.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Or txtCustomerAddress.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Or txtCustomerName.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Or txtCustomerAliasname.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Or txtacgroup.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Or txtcustomerOPAmount.Name = myForm.ActiveControl.Name Then
      Exit Sub
   Else
      deletionprocess(txtTIN, txtCustomerPhone, txtCustomerMobileno, txtCustomerEmail, txtCustomerAddress, btnCustomerSave, txtCustomerName, txtCustomerAliasname, txtacgroup, txtcustomerOPAmount, UC_autoCompleteComboBox1, errorProvider1)
   End If

End If
```